# MySQL count distinct values from JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of languages for each movie. I have the table `movies`

```
id  | movies
1   | movie-1
2   | movie-2
3   | movie-3
4   | movie-4
```

and the table `languages`

```
id  | movie_id | language
1   |    1     |  english
2   |    1     |  german
3   |    1     |  english
4   |    1     |  french
5   |    1     |  dutch
6   |    1     |  polish
7   |    1     |  russian
8   |    1     |  french
9   |    2     |  french
10  |    2     |  italian
11  |    2     |  english
```

The desired result for `movie-1` is `6`(french,russian,polish,english,dutch).  Movie-1 has 6 languages.  For `movie-2` the result would be 3(french,italian,english).

Here is my query attempt but not returning desired results:

```
SELECT COUNT(a3.language) 
FROM movies a2
JOIN languages a3 on a3.movie_id=a2.id
GROUP BY a3.language
```

How do i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the distinct languages, and also group by the `movie_id`, not the `language`:

```
SELECT m.id, COUNT(DISTINCT l.language) AS languages
FROM movies m
JOIN languages l ON l.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id
```

Output:

```
id  languages
1   6
2   3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/223f8d/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a2.id, COUNT(DISTINCT a3.language)
FROM movies a2
JOIN languages a3 ON a3.movie_id = a2.id
GROUP BY a2.id
```

Here one important point to remember, we do not use group by on the result of aggregator function but on a column. In this example we grouped by movie id not the count of language.

Against a movie Id you want to get all the languages then group by should be on movie id, on the other hand if lets say you have to find out count of movies by languages then you will have group by on language by applying count on movie ids.